# I have written an ajax code to download a file on form submission. The file downloads on Chrome browser, but doesn't work for Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

**This is the AJAX code for downloading the file.**

```js
<script>
  $.ajax({
                url : 'panel_download.php',
                type : 'POST',
                data : {name:name,email:email,company_name:company_name,ph_no:ph_no,panel_submit:panel_submit},
                success : function(data){           
                     //window.location.href = "docs/eaResponse-Panel_Book.pptx";
                     window.location.assign("docs/eaResponse-Panel_Book.pptx");
                     $('#name').val('');
                     $('#email').val('');
                     $('#company_name').val('');
                     $('#ph_no').val('');
                     $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                }
            });
  </script>
```

This code works on Chrome and Not Firefox

Comment: does it give u an error in console ?

Comment: post your `panel_download.php` code

Comment: no... it doesn't show any error in console